# /bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory Problem

Tags: google-colaboratory

When run this command found some error. can anyone help me?

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvMHO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have an executable file called "./darknet"
You have a darknet.py though, but that's a different one.